# Non-Asp H3 Element Creating Gap on Page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following `.aspx` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="BootStrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar" class="col-xs-12"></div>
    <h3> Loading... </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Where, after adding the `h3` tag I am seeing a gap above the `navbar` element:

[image]

After removing the `H3` element, the gap disappears:

[image]

I also noticed that if I amend the tag so that it reads:

`<asp:h3> Loading... </asp:h3>`

the gap also disappears, however I then get this warning in VS:

> Element 'h3' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.

Does anyone know what is causing this gap to appear when using non-asp elements on an asp page? Also, is that warning something I should be worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headings (from `h1` to `h6`) by default have `margin`, but because you are using bootstrap, it has it own styles applied to headings (in this case for `h1` to to `h3`) which are:

```css
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

so you need to reset `margin`

in your case:

```css
h3 {
  margin: 0
}
```